# GWT clickhandler doesn't hide it's own panel

Tags: gwt

For a menu implementation, i've added a clickhandler on a `FocusPanel`, containing a label. Clicking on the `FocusPanel` opens a `VerticalPanel`, with several other labels, each with ClickHandlers. Clicking on one of these labels changes the label in the `FocusPanel`. This part works fine. But for some reason i cannot hide the `VerticalPanel` after clicking on the label.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

I've added some sysout's, which tells me that the panel is in fact hidden, with top location = 0. However, it doesn't dissapear on the screen (tested in FF and Chrome).

```
final VerticalPanel popupPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    popupPanel.setVisible(false);
    popupPanel.setStyleName("popupGreen");
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        final Label option = new Label();
        final String text = options[i];
        option.setText(text);
        if (text.equals(chosen)) {
            option.addStyleName("selected");
        }
        option.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                textBox.setText(text);
                popupPanel.setVisible(false);
                popupPanel.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("display", "none");
                System.out.println(popupPanel.isVisible());
                System.out.println(popupPanel.getAbsoluteTop());
            }

        });
        popupPanel.add(option);
    }
    verticalPanel.add(popupPanel);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `VerticalPanel` is within the `FocusPanel` then the click event will bubble up and the `ClickHandler` on the `FocusPanel` will set the `VerticalPanel` visible again.

Comment: Thank you. Moving the panel outside the FocusPanel solved the problem.

Comment: Or you could `event.stopPropagation()` when you handle the click at the `VerticalPanel` level.